# Accessing Enums in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to read Enum via thymeleaf template

```
public enum OrderStatus{
 COMPLETE("Completed"),
 PENDING("Pending");

 private String status;

 public String getStatus(){
    return this.status;
 }
}
```

When I try to access this enum from thymeleaf

```
<div th:text=${T(com.order.enum.OrderStatus).COMPLETE.getStatus()}"/>
<div th:text=${T(com.order.enum.OrderStatus).valueOf('COMPLETE').getStatus()}"/>
```

it works. But The Status COMPLETE and PENDING is based on input from my controller. I am trying some thing like this

```
<div th:text=${T(com.order.enum.OrderStatus).${order.requestedStatus}.getStatus()}"/>
<div th:text=${T(com.order.enum.OrderStatus).valueOf('${order.requestedStatus}').getStatus()}"/>
```

I am getting the Could not parse as expression: for the first one
No enum constant  com.order.enum.OrderStatus.${order.requestedStatus} for the second one 
 Is there a way i can invoke the enum dynamically

My Order class

```
Class Order{
   private String requestedStatus;

   getters & setters
```

}

My controller Method

```
@GetMapping 
public string getOrder(Model model){
  model.addAttribute("order", Order);
  return "result"
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do here. Can you provide an example of the output you want to see?  I would have given you the same solution as @Chris. If your `order.requestedStatus` is a string, then I think that defeats the value of having an enum. The order object should contain an enum not a string.

Comment: Small point: The `OrderStatus` enum in the question will not compile, as written. It is missing a constructor, which is needed because you are using enum fields.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your template:

```
<div th:text=${order.requestedStatus.status}"/>
```

You only have to reference the enum like `T(com.order.enum.OrderStatus)` if you want to do a comparison or print the value of enum directly (not the value of one of your object that returns an enum).

Comment: In my order calls requestedStatus is a String. How does order.requestedStatus.status refer to the OrderStatus enum, can you please explain

Answer (score 0):

you can use the getter function like this:
`<td th:text="${order.getOrdersStatus()}"> </td>`